# Comepare two Theil-Sen estimators for significance

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, trend, estimators

Since an ANCOVA was not possible with my data, I moved on to use Mann-Kenndall as well as Theil-Sen estimators to analyze my data. 
I have three datasets. For two of them Sen's slopes were found to be significantly different from 0. Nevertheless these two slopes differ enormously:
The first one is barely significantly different from 0:

```
Sen's slope
data:  ts_datu
z = -1.9748, n = 7, p-value = 0.04829
alternative hypothesis: true z is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
-2.666667  0.000000
sample estimates:
Sen's slope 
-1
```

While the second one is very significantly different from 0:

```
Sen's slope
data:  ts_dats
z = -2.7034, n = 7, p-value = 0.006864 
alternative hypothesis: true z is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-6.5 -1.5
sample estimates:
Sen's slope 
-3.5
```

So now I know, that they are different from 0 but I would also like to know, if they are different from each other. Is there a way to test that?

Greetings
Sven

/edit
The image shows in red the first slope and in blue the second one. The data points belong to the blue line. As this outlier is more or less ignored, which is comepletly wrong concerning my question - it is not surprising that the slopes are not significantly different.

[image]

Comment: Are the reported confidence intervals for the slope estimate? If so, you could consider non- overlapping intervals to be statistically different.

Comment: Yes, I think those are the CIs for the slope.

Comment: So no I need to test if they are overlapping? In this case I would say they do, since the Values of the first slope are completely within the margins of the second slope. So I now would have to carry out a t-test on it, to see if they are significant different anyways? (according to this: https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/openair/html/TheilSen.html). Using the package mblm I calculated the SD for both slopes which is 3.017 for the first and 5.975 for the second.

Comment: So I calculated it by now and ended up with a value of 0.374, which is not a non significant difference. Since the slopes are so different I really cannot believe this. Might this not be appropriate? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: I added a graph to the original post to show, why I am not satisfied with the results. All slopes have the same starting point, which is not really taken into consideration by Sen's slope.

Comment: My idea was to simply look at the reported confidence intervals for the slopes to see if they overlap.  At least when this technique is used for means, it tends to be conservative in finding differences relative to a t-test.  I don't know how it is regarding Sen slope.

Comment: At least looking at the data you presented (which are the points for only one slope), I think you might be overestimating the statistical difference in the slopes.  Consider that you have only 7 data points.  You're comparing a slope of -1 to one of -3.5 on data that range in y from 80 to 110 over a change in x of 7.  Just eyeballing the red and blue lines, with the variation in the points shown, I wouldn't think that the slopes are necessarily different.

Comment: Tank you for your comment. I get what you mean and I can only agree on that. Nevertheless I would have thought the data would result in a steeper slope and therefore would be found to be significant. I just think, that the first data point is not taken into consideration by Sen's slope the way I would have expected. I also used pettitts test on the data and it tells me, that there is a change point only in week 4 which I would have expected to be found for week two, when the data changes the most. Nevertheless, I am going to work with these results and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: 1.  I would try changing the confidence interval in mblm from 0.95 to 0.90 and see the result. If the slopes are different there, I would just report that the 95% confidence intervals were overlapping but the 90% confidence intervals were not.

Comment: 2.  It might be useful to look at the data in some other ways.  Of course I'm not suggesting that you try to analyze the data different ways and then pick the result you like, but I'm wondering if mblm is the best approach.  a) If the shape of the other data follow that for the red group, maybe fitting a simple curve would be better than a line?  b)  If the shape of the other data follow that for the red group, maybe ignoring the data at week zero before fitting the slope?  (Cont...)

Comment: Does a slope for weeks 1 - 6 make sense?  c) Is it possible to transform the data and use you original ancova approach?